# HTML widgets in Jupyter R Notebook

Tags: r, widget, jupyter, plotly

Im unable to display HTML widgets in Jupyter Notebooks when using R (works when using python). For example none of the plotly charts work in Jupyter R notebook. Is there any solution for this?

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
        mode = "markers", color = carat, size = carat)
```

The code executes but no graph is displayed

Comment: you should save the widget out and use an `iframe` to read it back in (or write a wrapper that does that for you and emits the proper HTML for a notebook). or just use RStudio and forget the notebook nonsense :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a call to `embed_notebook` (see the examples [here](https://plot.ly/r/using-r-in-jupyter-notebooks)).

So change your code to:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
myPlot <- plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
        mode = "markers", color = carat, size = carat)
embed_notebook(myPlot)
```