# Error: "HTML widgets cannot be represented in plain text"

Tags: r, jupyter

When I try to run this by *Jupyter*:

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map
```

I get this error:

`HTML widgets cannot be represented in plain text (need html)`.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292161/html-widgets-in-jupyter-r-notebook) I have tried:

```
library(plotly)
embed_notebook(m)
```

but I get:

`Error in UseMethod("embed_notebook"): no applicable method for 'embed_notebook' applied to an object of class "c('leaflet', 'htmlwidget')`

How could I plot this kind of graph?

Answer (score 7):

embed_notebook is specifically defined for plotly objects. I would look through the documentation to see if leaflet has its own equivalent function.

Alternatively, since it's an html widget, you can save it as an html file, then embed that file inside of an iframe in your notebook. This can be accomplished with something like

```
library(IRdisplay)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(m, "m.html")
display_html('<iframe src="m.html" width=100% height=450></iframe>')
```

If you don't want to keep a bunch of html files in your folder, you can also enter the raw html of your widget into your iframe then delete it using

```
rawHTML = base64enc::dataURI(mime = "text/html;charset=utf-8", file = "m.html")
display_html(paste("<iframe src=", rawHTML, "width=100% height=450></iframe>", sep = "\""))
unlink("m.html")
```

But I've found that this generates an error with the most recent version of Chrome.

If it helps, I cobbled together the following function from the source code of embed_notebook

```
embed = function(x, height) {
    library(IRdisplay)
    tmp = tempfile(fileext = ".html")
    htmlwidgets::saveWidget(x, tmp)
    rawHTML = base64enc::dataURI(mime = "text/html;charset=utf-8", file = tmp)
    display_html(paste("<iframe src=", rawHTML, "width=100% height=", height, "id=","igraph", "scrolling=","no","seamless=","seamless", "frameBorder=","0","></iframe>", sep = "\""))
    unlink(tmp)
}
```

But again, this may not work for Chrome.

Comment: #cromulent  The issue is that `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(m, "m.html")` doesen't create the html file.

Comment: @Simone I apologize if this is insulting, but do you have the htmlwidgets package installed in your version of R? If you do, I'm not experienced enough to know what could be causing the problem on your end.

Comment: Yes, I have `htmlwidgets ` package installed

Comment: @cromulent It also doesn't create the html file for me when I run on R kernel in Jupyter. Works fine in RStudio. I don't have pandoc on JupyterHub, so have set selfcontained = FALSE, but is there anything else that would prevent it form running in Jupyter?